# how to properly control css3 animation speed

Tags: css, animation

I have borrowed a css3 "work rotation" animation, in which a given "work is rotated every 3 seconds.
I'm trying to speed it up to 1.5 seconds by manipulating css animation-delay values, but I just ending up with those words clobbering each other, instead of replacing.

Here is the css:

```
#sentence-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    padding: 10px;
}
.sentence{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.sentence span{
    color: #444;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.words{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
.words-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #6b969d;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    color: #6b889d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    color: #6b739d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
    -o-animation-delay: 9s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
    animation-delay: 9s;
    color: #7a6b9d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
    color: #8d6b9d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 15s;
    -o-animation-delay: 15s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    color: #9b6b9d;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Here is my current fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/2y81qLd6/

How do I properly adjust these settings, to have the rotation take 1.5 seconds instead of full 3?

Comment: change animation-duration to half the value 18s / 2 = 9s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the main duration and all the delays in half.

```
.words-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #6b969d;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWord 9s linear infinite 0s;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    color: #6b889d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 3s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    color: #6b739d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 4.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 4.5s;
    animation-delay: 4.5s;
    color: #7a6b9d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
    color: #8d6b9d;
}
.words-1 span:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    color: #9b6b9d;
}
```

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2y81qLd6/1/